# Java Replacing Characters

Tags: java, regex

This is pretty simple but how would I create a regex to strip anything but

- letters a-Z,
- numbers 0-9
- and commas?

I think the regex expression for the first two is `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]` but how could I add commas to it.

Also, would it be the following?

```
"string".replaceAll("expression", null);
```

Comment: Add the comma in the square brackets as well. For instance [^a-z,]

Comment: Do you want also to prevent `_` from being removed? If not then why is it in your `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]` regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can simply add comma to your [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

  ```
  [^a-zA-Z0-9,]
             ^ add this
  ```
- Also Strings are immutable so `replaceAll` will not affect original string but create new one with replaced characters so you need to store it somewhere (maybe in reference to original String).
- Last thing is that you need to pass empty string `""` as replacement, not `null`.

So try with

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]","");
```

---

Another thing is that regex you are currently using also prevents `_` from being removed. If that was intentional then instead of `_` `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` you can simply use predefined character class `\w` (which in Javas String needs to be written as `"\\w"` because `\` needs to be escaped) so your code can look like

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("[^\\w,]","");
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can not use `null` for the replacement value. It will give you `java.lang.NullPointerException`. You must use string there. For example instead of `null` use empty `""`.

About the regex, if you need anything to add inside your character class `[]`, just add them there. For example `[^a-z,*.]`

Furthermore, your `a-zA-Z_0-9` can be replaced with `\\w`

```
[^\\w,]
```

Comment: `\\w` includes `_` which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Pshemo in OP's example `_` exists.

Comment: `letters a-Z, numbers 0-9 and commas` I don't see anything about preventing `_` from being replaced.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous as to whether _ should be included.  It's in the OP's attempt but not the description.  This ambiguity is manifested in Pshemo's own answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, I just realised that there is `_` in OP regex while it is not mentioned in his requirements. I suspect that OP just found this regex somewhere with `_` and used it so handling `_` may be not intentional.

Comment: @Pshemo - Hah, you didn't need to edit it on my account.  I was just stirring :-)  I hope OP is capable of working out for himself/herself whether or not to include underscores.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should do:

```
value = "string".replaceAll("[\\W_,]", "");
```

My pattern doesn't use negation.

You should replace it with empty string and not `null` and you've to assign the result to your string as strings are immutable.

You can just simplify your regex to mine.

Otherwise just add `,` to your negated character class.

Answer (score 0):

`[\w,]+` is the regex which matches alphanumeric, underscore and comma.

Here `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

`[\W,]+` is the regex which matches everything except alphanumeric, underscore and comma.

Here `\W` - Matches any character that is not a word character (alphanumeric & underscore) which is equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`